# git --no-replace-objects ineffective when changing submodule ref

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have super-repo/submodule structure where some submodules need to be migrated to another upstream source. The submodule itself is using git-replace internally in order to mimick the behavior of the old upstream source (git histories are unrelated but the replace refs ensure that old commits can be found).

What I could not achieve is easy editing of the super repo in cases where I want to migrate an existing branch there at once to point to the new refs. However, doing that without new commits on the submodule!

When I do a `git add smfolder` there, nothing happens. git seems to assume that the SM is unchanged. And it might look unchanged but the reference stored in super-repo is still the old one, and I wish to convert it to a new one.

I have even tried `git --no-replace-objects add smfolder` following git-replace manpage. This is also not effective. What else can I use to overcome this shadowing from git-replace?

Comment: Interesting - if you've replaced commit X with commit Y in repository `sm` (the submodule), what happens if you enter `sm` and run `git checkout X` with the raw hash ID `X`? In particular, afterward, what does `git rev-parse HEAD` show: X, or Y?

Comment: If you enter the `sm` and do a checkout of X then ```git show``` will present X as top commit but with a comment `(HEAD, replaced)`, so you actually don't see the Y hash anywhere. `git rev-parse HEAD` shows the same, X. The only reliable way found so far is simply reading the file `$topdir/.git/modules/bm_common/refs/replace/X` manually.

Comment: OK, that kind of adds together with the experience you have so far in terms of not seeing anything to change in the superproject. What you *want* is to have `git add` find the replacement hash Y, so that it adds a gitlink to commit Y (the replacement) rather than hash X (the original). Making that happen easily/automatically is going to be the problem. Rather than reading the *file* though, use `git -C sm rev-parse refs/replace/X` to get Y.

Comment: Feed the replacement to a `git checkout` in the submodule (`git -C sm checkout Y`, more or less) for each submodule for which there's a replacement. Then `git add` in the superproject should add the right hash ID, and `git commit` in the superproject will record hash Y instead of hash X.